# python regex match for non-fraction and fractions

Tags: python, regex

I have the following text in a pandas column that I'm trying to create a regular expression to sort into individual columns

```
2 Table $75
5 Chairs 875 Teabags
9/10 gel 125 Dishwasher tablets
```

My first attempt works for the first line of text and some of the last line but not the middle line for the most part:

```
^(\d+)\D+(\d+)\D+(\d+)
```

But my second iteration to account for an "or" condition fails to cause any reasonable match:

```
^(\d+|\d+\/\d+)\D+(\d+)\D+(\d+)
```

Example [here](https://regex101.com/r/H74dJb/1)

How can I restructure the above to account for the differences and catch all the numbers and fractions?

Comment: `\D` also matches a newline, try it like this with an optional non capturing group `^(\d+(?:\/\d+)?)[^\d\n]+(\d+)` https://regex101.com/r/YUHhZW/1

Comment: Your example input has two numbers on each line, but your regex seems to look for three numbers (in capture groups). Can you clarify how many numbers you want to capture per line? And is it guaranteed this is the same for each line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

data = {'text_column': ['2 Table $75', '5 Chairs 875 Teabags', '9/10 gel 125 Dishwasher tablets']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

pattern = r'(\d+(?:/\d+)?)\s*([a-zA-Z]+)|([a-zA-Z]+)'   # to extract numerical values, fractions

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    matches = re.findall(pattern, row['text_column'])
    for match in matches:
        if match[0]:          # numeric value or fraction
            print(f"Match: {match[0]} ")
    print()
```

Output:

```
Match: 2

Match: 5
Match: 875

Match: 9/10
Match: 125
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Very helpful. One part I do not understand is that you have made a non-capturing group optional? (?:)? How is the non-capturing group then working to capture?

Comment: ur welcome, (?:/\d+)? makes the fraction part, such as /10 in 9/10, optional. If there's a fraction, it will be matched; if not, it will still match the whole numbers.

Comment: But if it matches as it's a non capturing group it won't save it is my understanding. Why is it saved in a group then?

Comment: @Dan it's because that group is *inside* a capturing group, so that group captures *both* parts of the fraction.